# ReactJS use a ready-made template (from template monster)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, html-templates

I'm learning to build a project in ReactJS with Typescript at the moment.

I have bought an HTML template from templatemonster. This is a very good template and has all the UI items I need to use for my project.

I have tried to import this to my ReactJS project.

I have successfully loaded all the css of the template and have made it look almost like it should for a start.

The issue is that the template from templatemonster is using two javascript scripts

`core.min.js` and `script.js` that need to be loaded as they control how some of the view items are working. Like how the accordions are opening/closing. Some of the animations, ui stuff in forms etc.

I load them using `useEffect` in my `Header` component:

Example:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = "../js/core.min.js";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, []);
```

I'm getting the following error for those scripts:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Is there any way to load a javascript file in react that won't have an issue with `$`?